# Handling MySql Group By

Tags: mysql

Below is the mysql code

```
CREATE TABLE pricing
( 
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `cost` FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    `valid_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, `quantity` INT NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO pricing (`id`, `cost`, `valid_on`, `quantity`) VALUES 
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-01 00:00:00', '1'), 
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-02 00:00:00', '1'),
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-03 00:00:00', '1'),
(NULL, '5', '2017-01-04 00:00:00', '2'),
(NULL, '5', '2017-01-05 00:00:00', '2'),
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-06 00:00:00', '2'),
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-07 00:00:00', '3'),
(NULL, '5', '2017-01-08 00:00:00', '3'),
(NULL, '5', '2017-01-09 00:00:00', '3'),
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-10 00:00:00', '3'),
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-11 00:00:00', '3'),
(NULL, '4', '2017-01-12 00:00:00', '2'),
(NULL, '5', '2017-01-13 00:00:00', '2'),
(NULL, '5', '2017-01-14 00:00:00', '2');
```

So when Group By is done on quantity following results are displayed.

```
select quantity, sum(cost) from pricing GROUP BY quantity

1 - 12

2 - 28

3 - 22
```

But actually I need something like the below results.

```
 quantity     start_date             end_date          cost

    1     2017-01-01 00:00:00    2017-01-03 00:00:00    12

    2     2017-01-04 00:00:00    2017-01-06 00:00:00    14

    3     2017-01-07 00:00:00    2017-01-11 00:00:00    22

    2     2017-01-12 00:00:00    2017-01-14 00:00:00    14
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/460ae9c/1)

Can someone please help me solve this issue...

Comment: From the expected result it's clear that you don't need to `GROUP BY quantity` but have some different grouping criterion that relies on the order of rows. This is not quite a job for SQL but, using some tricks (like variables), MySQL can do it.

Comment: Yes its not a group by but @Giorgos Betsos gave the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT quantity, 
       MIN(valid_on) AS start_date, MAX(valid_on) AS end_date,
       SUM(cost)
FROM (
   SELECT id, cost, valid_on, quantity,
          @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
          @grn := IF(@q = quantity, @grn + 1,
                     IF(@q := quantity, 1, 1)) AS grp
   FROM pricing
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @q := 0, @grn := 0) AS vars
   ORDER BY valid_on, quantity) AS t
GROUP BY rn - grp, quantity
```

The query uses variables in order to identify islands of consecutive records having the same `quantity` value. Using the computed `grp` value, it groups separately each island and calculates start/end dates, as well as the sum of `cost`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/438d63/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain to do in MySQL.  You need to identify the groups.  One method -- which is not particularly efficient -- uses a trick.  For each row it counts the number of previous rows where the quantity is *different* from the given row.  This identifies adjacent groups with the same value.

```
select quantity, sum(cost), min(valid_on) as start_valid_on
from (select p.*,
             (select count(*)
              from pricing p2
              where p2.valid_on < p.valid_on and p2.quantity <> p.quantity
             ) as grp
      from pricing p
     ) p
group by grp, quantity;
```